# How to graph user input equation in plotly/Streamlit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, streamlit

I'm creating a Streamlit app with multiple timeseries plotted in a line chart as below. I want to provide functionality for the user to input dynamic equations like GOOG-AAPL or NFLX+MSFT and plot the output in the same chart. Is this possible?

```
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x="date", y=df.columns,
              hover_data={"date": "|%B %d, %Y"},
              title='custom tick labels')
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="M1",
    tickformat="%b\n%Y")

st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.
If the set of formulas is limited, you could add dropdown selection widgets for the names as well as a widget (radio button) to select the function (add, subtract). Then you can add the resulting column to the dataframe and refresh the graph.

A good example to start and learn from is this one:

https://plotly.com/python/figurewidget-app/